# From string to milliseconds and back

Tags: php, time

I want to make some operations with two hours stored in vars. I first convert to milliseconds make the operations and then convert back to something readable. It seems to work but the final number is not right. In this example it gives me 1:30:00 of difference. Can someone explain why?

```
// I have two hours that come from a MySql database and I store in a var:
$start= "16:00:00";
$end= "16:30:00";

// I convert to milliseconds and rest:
$startMili = strtotime($start);
$endMili = strtotime($end);
$dif = $endMili - $startMili ;

// convert to something readable:
echo "<br><br> diference: ";
$readable = date("H:i:s", $dif);
echo $readable;
```

Comment: The _strtotime_ and _date_ functions are meant for absolute timestamps, not intervals! The additional hour might come from your timezone settings (_date_default_timezone_set_). Maybe you could use _TIMEDIFF_ function directly in your SQL query?

Comment: When I try your code I get the correct result of 0:30:00

Comment: @Perry. It's strange. Perhaps it is the timezone as Piotr says. I am in Barcelona. Where are you?

Comment: @Nrc I did not change the time zone, it was UTC. But when I change the timezone to Amsterdam that is the same as Barcelona I get also 1:30:00. See also my answer, that is working even when changing the time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use also DateTime instead of strtotime

see below the example

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($start, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
$datetime2 = new DateTime($end, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%i:%s');
```